# Im trying to make a simple website. But something's wrong with my code

Tags: javascript

```
const loginInput = document.querySelector("#login-form input");
const loginButton = document.querySelector("#login-form button");

function onLoginBtnClick() {
    const value = loginInput.value;
    if (value === "") {
        alert("Please write your name.");
    }
}

loginButton.addEventListener("click", onLoginBtnClick);
```

It's JS code.

I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" error.
I'm trying to make a site that displays the username in the console window when I enter the username and click the login button.

I tried to change the code in line 1~2 as below.

```
const loginForm = document.getElementById("#login-form");
const loginInput = loginForm.querySelector("input");
const loginButton = loginForm.querySelector("button");
```

Comment: Make sure your code is executing at the right point of time, meaning it needs to execute after those elements exist in the DOM otherwise they will not be found.

Comment: If you are getting elements by id, you only need to indicate the name of the id (without the `#`)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `document.getElementById("#login-form");` it's not going to work - when you do `getElementById` you don't prefix the id with a `#`, whereas with with `.querySelector` you do (to indicate that it is the ID)

Comment: OP is probably running the script too early. He did not make this mistake in the first snippet, and he said that it didn't work.